# Why my UIButton image icon's size on emulator or device is not the same as in interface builder

Tags: ios, image, uibutton

I create a button which is look like this in interface builder

See the Login Button
[image]

But somehow when I run it on emulator or device the icon become smaller like this.

[image]

I don't know why it is smaller. I haven't done anything on that button in code.

How can I solve this?
Thanks.

**Solved**

---

Because 2x image and normal image of icon are the same size.
By double the size of 2x image. Then it is solved.

Comment: Have you added @2x image for ratina diplay ? if yes then check its name too

Comment: do you use autolayout ?

Comment: yes i have 2x image but i make both normal image and @2x image have the same size because the original image is 21*21 pixel. i think it is small enough. I use auto layout

Comment: it's might be because of retina image ..

Comment: ok it's solve i have to increase the size of 2x image thank you.